# Dynamically generate SSRS reports in asp.net Mvc using Entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, reporting-services

I have an MVC application with Entity Framework.For dynamically  generating reports I like TO use SSRS reports.I am completely new to SSRS.Plz help

Comment: If you like using api's then here is one approach for management-->https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.aspx

Comment: Another service for rendering here --> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.aspx